# Using list comprehension with two variables in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, list-comprehension

does someone know how I can do a list comprehension with two variables in haskell?

ex.

```
[ x * y  | x <- [1..10]  y <- [1..10]]
```

it should result in

```
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

but it actually yields in ghci

```
<interactive>:13:23-24: error:
    parse error on input ‘<-’
    Perhaps this statement should be within a 'do' block?
```

Comment: Generators are separated by commas, so `[ x * y  | x <- [1..10],  y <- [1..10]]` will type check, but won't give you the output you want. `[x * x | x <- [1..10]]` will work, but only requires a single generator.

Comment: thanks! this really helped a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well there are two problems here: a *syntactical* one, and a *semantical* one.

## Towards a valid list comprehension expression

The syntactical one is that you separate the parts of list comprehension (these can be *generators*, *filters*, and `let` clauses) by a **comma (`,`)**:

```
[ x * y  | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..10]]
```

But now we will *not* get the desired output. Indeed:

```
Prelude> [ x * y  | x <- [1..10], y <- [1..10]]
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60,7,14,21,28,35,42,49,56,63,70,8,16,24,32,40,48,56,64,72,80,9,18,27,36,45,54,63,72,81,90,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
```

What we here have is all multiplications between two integers from `1` to `10`. Since for every `x` in the list `[1..10]`, we iterate through the list `[1..10]` for `y`. This however does not match with your requested list, hence a semantical error.

## Obtaining a list of squares

What you seem to want is a list of all *square* numbers. In that case there is only *one* variable `x`, and for each value of `x`, we yield `x*x`:

```
[ x * x  | x <- [1..10]]
```

this then yields:

```
Prelude> [ x * x  | x <- [1..10]]
[1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100]
```

## Enumerating lists in parallel

In case you have two lists you want to enumerate in parallel, you can do this with a `zip`, for example if we want to multiply the elements of `[1..10]` with the elements of `[5..14]` *elementwise*, we can do this with:

```
[ x * y  | (x, y) <- zip [1..10] [5..14]]
```

We can also work with the [**`ParallelListComp`** extension](https://ghc.readthedocs.io/en/8.0.2/glasgow_exts.html#parallel-list-comprehensions) as [@DanielWagner says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451401/using-list-comprehension-with-two-variables-in-haskell/50451580#comment87920549_50451580):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

[ x * y  | x <- [1..10] | y <- [5..14]]
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning `ParallelListComp` and `[x*y | x <- [1..10] | y <- [1..10]]`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to zip the two ranges together:

```
[ x * y | (x, y) <- zip [1..10] [1..10] ]
```

You *can* have two separate iterators, separated with a comma

```
[ x * y | x <- [1..10], y <-[1..10] ]
```

but this computes the cartesian product of the two sets, resulting in a full multiplication table rather a list of squares.